# reading certain digits from binary data

Tags: c#, python, binary

I have one python script which i am trying to convert and stuck in one place and unable to proceed. Please check where ever i have mentioned "Stuck here" in below code. any help would be appreciated

Original Python script:

```
import hashlib
meid = raw_input("Enter an MEID: ").upper()
s = hashlib.sha1(meid.decode('hex'))
#decode the hex MEID (convert it to binary!)
pesn = "80" + s.hexdigest()[-6:].upper()
#put the last 6 digits of the hash after 80
print "pESN: " + pesn
```

My C# conversion:

```
UInt64 EsnDec = 2161133276;
string EsnHex=string.Format("{0:x}", EsnDec);
string m = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(EsnHex, 16), 2);
/*---------------------------------------------
Stuck here. Now m got complete binary data
and i need to take last 6 digits as per python
script and prefix "80". 
---------------------------------------------*/
Console.WriteLine(m);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: [m.Substring would seem to be the right choice.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

Comment: Agreed. To take the last `n` digits of a string `s`, you can use: `s.Substring(s.Length - n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UInt64 EsnDec = 2161133276;
    Console.WriteLine(EsnDec);
    //Convert to String
    string Esn = EsnDec.ToString();
    Esn = "80" + Esn.Substring(Esn.Length - 6);
    //Convert back to UInt64
    EsnDec = Convert.ToUInt64(Esn);
    Console.WriteLine(EsnDec);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: The last 6 decimal characters will be the last 20 bits. I think the OP wants the last 6 bits; which is ~1.5 dec characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx):

```
// last 6 characters
string lastsix = m.Substring(m.Length - 6);

Console.WriteLine("80{0}", lastsix);
```